# Why calling a predefined function during events has different syntax when called from HTML/JS?

Tags: javascript, html

When we have a predefined JS function:

```
function myFunction() { script }
```

Why when we call it during an event (for e.g onclick) from HTML, we use the parameter parentheses:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Sumbit</button>
```

while when we call it from JS, we use the function name without parentheses?:

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = myFunction;
```

Comment: That's just how it is defined: to the `onclick` attribute you must provide an expression, while the `onclick` property needs a function reference.

Comment: `on` is a prefix that gets added to inline HTML event attributes to denote what JavaScript to execute when the event happens. The event is just `click`. It's also used on event properties in JavaScript.

Both of these techniques are old and antiquated and should no longer be used.  Instead, follow modern standards and use `.addEventListener()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `onclick="myFunction()"`, JS runs the code inside `""` as an expression, so why we call our function there. Means that when `click` is occurred call that function.

With `.onclick = myFunction`, we assign a *reference of the function* to the `onclick` property, which is called when the `click` is occurred. It may be called like something this

```
// Somewhere when the click is detected

if(triggeredClick) {
   this.onclick();
}
```

Here the function is called, via the `onclick`, which refers to the function.

Answer (score 0):

When we have a predefined JS function:

> `function myFunction() { script }`

We call it during an event (for e.g onclick) from HTML, we use the parameter parentheses:

> `<button onclick="myFunction()">Sumbit</button>`
>
> Because:
>
> 1. Above "myFunction" is loosely coupled with any HTML element
> 2. Above "myFunction" can be called by multiple HTML elements
> 3. Above "myFunction" can be called on different events (onClick, onChange etc.)

While when we call it from JS, we use the function name without parentheses:

> `document.getElementById("button").onclick = myFunction;`
>
> Because:
>
> 1. Above "myFunction" is tightly coupled with any HTML element with Id "button"
> 2. Above "myFunction" can ONLY be called by HTML element with Id "button"
> 3. Above "myFunction" can ONLY be called by "onClick" event and no other